# Why explicity cast right side pointer operand if type matches left side operand?

Tags: c, pointers, casting, variable-assignment

With respect to C programming, I'm seeing several cases in example code where pointer assignments involve an explicit cast of the right side operand even when it already matches the type of the left side operand.  Just one example:

```
void memcpy(u8int *dest, const u8int *src, u32int len)
{
    const u8int *sp = (const u8int *)src;
    u8int *dp = (u8int *)dest;
    for(; len != 0; len--) *dp++ = *sp++;
}
```

Of course, the function is also declared correctly in a header file as:

```
void memcpy(u8int * dest, const u8int * src, u32int len);
```

The function already defines the variable "src" as type "const u8int *", so why is it given an explicit cast when assigned to "sp" which is also of type "const u8int *"?  The same goes for the assignment of "dest" to "dp".

Comment: No point, perhaps somebody just learned casting?

Comment: Someone writing code like that is probably too afraid of cosmic noise altering the type of his variables :-)

Comment: he doesnt even need local variables looking at what this function does...

Comment: Thought maybe it could have been the result of some odd portability issues, but glad to know most agree it's just pointless.  That's the answer I was hoping to hear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're looking for a magical mysterious reason to do this, you'll be disappointed. There's no point to this type of explicit typecasting.

This was a style decision (and IMO a bad one) of the programmer. Typecasting has potential dangers (by "masking" important warnings) and making the code more complex to read... it should be reserved for situations where it's needed. This is not one of them.

Answer (score 1):

No use of doing this when they are of the same type already.  And it is a bad practise ofcourse.

Perhaps you reading the wrong book.

Answer (score 1):

my guess is that it is just the left-over of a find/replace operation, there is no reason to do this.

Answer (score 0):

He may just be that he is religiously writing code, with no meaning behind it (an habit).

Well only the programmer which wrote this code know what he was doing (or he doesnt). This function may overwrite the `memcpy()` from `string.h` because you cannot have two functions of the same name. Knowing that, he is into dangerous waters. And you too if you have to use this .